# how to pass Cron component sowText data to my other input in the same main component. reactjs

Tags: reactjs

these both are in same class based component

```js
<Cron
onRef={ref => (this.cronGen = ref)}
onChange={(e) => { this.setState({ croninput: e }); console.log(e) }} 
value={this.state.croninput}
showResultText={true}
showResultCron={false}
/>



<td style={{ width: "22%" }}><Input value={props.showResultText} /></td>
```